# Any relation between svm_train data's order and result?

Tags: python, svm, libsvm

I'm using `libSVM` with `Python`.

And I feel the question.

In using un-ordered index train data, I got un-expect result.

For example, result of operating set of some articles unclassified are all same such as:

> [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, ..., 1]

This is part of Train data.

> 4 133:1 25806:1 85:1 107:1 25806:1 12337:1 136:1 16943:1 15259:1 34:1 2019:1 173:1 1070:1 71:1 357:1 5518:1 178:1 179:1 5:1 12337:1 120:1 39912:1 120:1 2019:1 173:1 1070:1 71:1 357:1 5518:1 178:1 179:1 5:1 12337:1 6409:1 87:1 189:1 6410:1 133:1 25806:1 85:1 107:1 25806:1 12337:1 136:1 16943:1 15259:1 34:1 2019:1 173:1 1070:1 71:1 357:1 5518:1 178:1 179:1 5:1 12337:1 120:1 39912:1 1771:1 9:1 10:1 11:1 43188:1 27:1 6707:1 173:1 15:1 883:1 29:1 67:1 698:1 58:1 25806:1 5462:1 5511:1 34:1 16943:1 15259:1 224:1 128:1 167:1 312:1 1062:1 4140:1 184:1 71:1 357:1 193:1 907:1 167:1 698:1 564:1 11:1 1149:1 34:1 30261:1 10899:1 217:1 860:1 58:1 276:1 5:1 6088:1 398:1 177:1 178:1 179:1 5:1 25806:1 29:1 181:1 84:1 12337:1 84:1 58:1 665:1 357:1 897:1 650:1 178:1 4:1 5:1 1195:1 29:1 80:1 17:1 186:1 10:1 11:1 7495:1 167:1 22073:1 5:1 230:1 29:1 179:1 51:1 1874:1 167:1 22073:1 5:1 230:1 17:1 179:1 80:1 867:1 15:1 324:1 185:1 350:1 2914:1 5:1 84:1 39912:1

Following above data, you can understand that index are not ordered.

I think it is the problem. Any other reason for this case?

PS. train meta(y) was distributed:

> **1** 1:1 2:1 3:1 4:1 5:1 2:1 6:1 7:1 8:1 9:1 10:1 11:1 12:1 13:1 14:1 15:1 16:1 17:1 18:1 19:1 20:1 21:1 22:1 11:1 1:1 2:1 23:1 24:1 25:1 26:1 27:1 28:1 29:1 30:1 31:1 32:1 8:1 15:1 33:1 17:1 21:1 22:1 34:1 35:1 17:1 36:1 10:1 11:1 37:1 33:1 38:1 39:1 40:1 41:1 42:1 43:1 44:1 45:1 46:1 47:1 32:1 48:1 49:1 50:1 15:1 16:1 45:1 51:1 52:1
>   **2** 309:1 310:1 217:1 968:1 4092:1 5:1 13544:1 32:1 13545:1 13546:1 13544:1 1064:1 13547:1 7287:1 2225:1 13548:1 2819:1 71:1 1269:1 132:1 13549:1 419:1 4698:1 87:1 6013:1 27:1 294:1 9:1 10:1 11:1 324:1 58:1 309:1 310:1 62:1 5459:1 350:1 1460:1 15:1 6026:1 5:1 13544:1 1949:1 185:1 186:1 10:1 32:1 439:1 139:1
>   ..
>   ..

Thank you!

Comment: Why do you have 2 or 4 as the first element of your training set lines? Do you have multiple classes? The first number is the class label and in a binary classification it should be 0 or 1 (or -1 or 1)

Comment: Yep. I have various classes. Your thought is right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theoretically there should not be an issue if the feature elements are not ordered as long as they are labeled correctly, however one must go through the libsvm code to be sure about this behavior (nothing in the documentation prohibits that).

In your case nonetheless, the problem may be class labeling. In a binary classification, the training data should have the following form:

```
0 1:xx 4:xx 3:xx ...
0 1:xx 2:xx 9:xx ...
1 1:xx 5:xx 13:xx ...
1 2:xx 3:xx 6:xx ...
```

with the first number being the class label. You need more or less equal number of feature sets for each class to get the best result.

Comment: Thank you. If I have multiple class, what can I do? I'm making `Documents Classifier`. Documents have various class such as economy, politics and etc. So I have to define that this is a part of Category.

Comment: If you have multiple classes you can label your negative data as 0, and label other classes as 1, 2, 3, and so on. If you don't have negative data and everything must belong to a class, you an use any number you want. libsvm uses 1-to-1 classification for multi-class approach so it really doesn't matter. The result of libsvm multi-class testing is always a class label which is the winner of all 1-to-1 classifications. One note: if you have a 60'000 dimensional feature vectors, you need thousands and thousands of training data "per class" to get anything good out of your SVM training.

Comment: aha. What do you mean of multi-class on document which A or B? `A` is a Document has classes more than one. `B` is Documents have domain of class as possible as various, but result expected is only one. I think multi-class is something like `B`. In `A`, label could be (3,4,5,..,n). While In `B`, label could only one value of (3,4,5,...,n). what do you mean? thank you.

Comment: Multi-class SVM in libsvm means each item has one class (label) out of many. It is similar to your 'B' case. If you have a situation where a document can have multiple labels (e.g.  Economy and Politics) then you have to do multiple binary classifications where in each one "features of documents with that attribute" (label = 1) are compared to "features of documents that do not have that attribute" (label = 0) regardless of if they have other attributes or not. The result from all classifications can then be combined to form multiple labels for a single document.

Comment: OMG. Thanks a lot! I want to do type B. Your advices were helpful to me. I'm going to keeping on researching more.